# consolidate rows for categorization

Tags: r, aggregate

If I have a df:

```
> ID<-c("A","A","A","B","B","B","B","C","C","C","C")
> attr<-c("yes1","yes1","no","yes2","yes1","yes1","yes1","no","no","yes1","yes2")
> df = data.frame(ID, attr) ; df
   ID attr
1   A yes1
2   A yes1
3   A   no
4   B yes2
5   B yes1
6   B yes1
7   B yes1
8   C   no
9   C   no
10  C yes1
11  C yes2
```

With thousands of IDs. I'd like to add another column that outputs the percent of `"yes"` attributes per ID, as well as if there was only one `"no"` attr:

```
     ID    %yes   #no
1     A    66.7     1
2     B     100     0
3     C      50     2
```

Is there a way to consolidate rows, akin to the SQL `GROUP BY`? Ultimately this new df would categorize IDs and be added into the original df:

```
     ID    attr    result
1     A    yes1       Pos
2     A    yes1       Pos
3     A      no     False
4     B    yes2   TruePos
5     B    yes1   TruePos
6     B    yes1   TruePos
7     B    yes1   TruePos
8     C      no     False
9     C      no     False
10    C    yes1       Pos
11    C    yes2       Pos
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `data.table` package:

Load the package and convert your `data.frame` to a `data.table`. Use `key=` to specify your grouping column.

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df, key="ID")
```

Perform your aggregation.

```
DT2 <- DT[, list(pct = length(grep("yes", attr))/length(attr),
                 no = sum(attr == "no")), by=key(DT)]
DT2
#    ID       pct no
# 1:  A 0.6666667  1
# 2:  B 1.0000000  0
# 3:  C 0.5000000  2
```

Comment: I've come across data.table a couple times now and I'll have to read the documentation. Seems like it has everything!

Comment: I just read the intro and the FAQ for `data.table` today. While the basic idea sounds great, I was slightly put off by the amount of things they changed in new releases. I am not necessarily a big fan of backwards compatibility, but it looks like it is a bit of a gamble whether today's R scripts will work with tomorrow's `data.table` releases.

Comment: @StephanKolassa, the developer is quite active here on SO, so I find that... comforting. I've found that for a lot of aggregation problems, it's super fast, and the syntax isn't too hard to pick up. What sorts of changes have you been put off by?

Comment: @StephanKolassa A bit of a gamble? What the hec are you on about??? We jump through hoops to keep it backwards compatible, over 800 tests etc etc.  All the changes are new features.  Please explain further.

Comment: As I said, I only read through the intro and the FAQ (as of 11/08). FAQs 1.11, 2.2, 2.6, (2.10), 2.21 mention changes in behavior and the dropping of an alias (`DT`). I rather frequently have to dust off old scripts and have had them break on me because of similar changes in packages. I have seen a lot of enthusiasm on StackOverflow and really like what I am reading in the `data.table` intro and FAQ, so I may definitely try working with it, but it sounds like there may be some breakage in store for me. Am I misunderstanding the FAQ?

Comment: @StephanKolassa. I see now, thanks. You're quite right but those 4 changes were ages ago: v1.3 (May 2010), v1.5.3 (Feb 2011) and v1.6.1 (Jun 2011). In the context of 158 bug fixes and 77 new features added. Maybe the FAQ should include dates, and an archive section. Since June 2011, and the package has become more used, we've become more refrained. The recent change in 1.8.3 (suppressing := printing, FAQ 2.21) was a change to a recent new feature (:=). That was only about printing at the console; it wouldn't break any scripts that had (quickly) started to use :=.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Dropping J() outside DT[...], on the other hand, did break some scripts and one dependent package in particular. But we knew in advance, gave many months notice period on datatable-help and in NEWS, and defining the alias yourself is trivial. It still hasn't been fully dropped actually. The reason we dropped it was it wasn't documented, and, it conflicted with rJava::J, meaning data.table can't be used with rJava currently until we fully drop it in the next version.

Comment: @MatthewDowle: thanks for the detailed answer, +1! As I said, I will probably take `data.table` for a test drive sometime (just installed it). I am slightly amused at how Jun 2011 is "ages ago" for you...

Comment: @StephanKolassa  Ha. You've got me thinking now. I suppose you need to know this ... is data.table2 planned soon? No, not at all. There's nothing I can think of that's blocked by backwards incompatibility concerns. Perhaps browse through each of the 100 feature requests and that should give you a better idea of what lies ahead.

Answer (score 2):

This will give you the proportion of "yes" per ID level:

```
by(substr(df$attr,1,3)=="yes",INDICES=df$ID,FUN=mean)
```

And this will tell you the number of "no" entries per ID level:

```
by(df$attr=="no",INDICES=df$ID,FUN=sum)
```